# Django templates folder

Tags: python, django

I want to create a "templates" folder in my project's root folder

When I do this:

```
{% extends "base.html "%}
```

I get a "TemplateDoesNotExist" error.

Here is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

Here is the template configuration from settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

The logs:

[image: logs]

(Using Django 2.0.dev20170914122638)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a typo problem, you have a 'space' after **base.html** in the {% extends "base.html " %} on that template.
Try:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```